# React Native Shake Event Detector Not Working

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, shake

I m using **react-native-shake: 3.2.2** package for shake gesture in my react native project.

```
react: 16.6.1 
react-native: 0.57.5
```

And here is my code.

```
    export default class Starting extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null,
        };

        showMessage() {
            Alert.alert('shakee!!');
        };

        componentWillMount() {
            RNShake.addEventListener('shake', () => {
                showMessage();
            });
        }

         componentWillUnmount() {
           RNShake.removeEventListener('shake');
         }
        render() {
    return (
.
.
.
}
```

On Xcode, I added **libRNShakeEvent.a** to Link Binary With Libraries and in shame i set my build configuration to **release**. According to react-native-shake package read me, thease are all things to do. 
But nothing happens while i shake the phone. 
What is wrong ?